# Monkey-patching XMLHttpRequest.send for special url

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to create an http-interceptor that will allow to add header to requests sent from within third-party app. I'm monkey-patching `XMLHttpRequest.send`

```
const origSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    this.setRequestHeader("A-Header", "Value");
    return origSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

The problem is that I don't need that header in other requests, still I don't see how can I access request url (to check if request is made from third-party lib). How can I make this interceptor work only in case there's a substring in url?

Comment: You could monkey patch `.open` and store the url in the instance: https://jsfiddle.net/9q01mv7p/

Comment: @ChrisG great idea! Can you please post this as answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also monkey-patch the `.open()` method, you can store the passed url in the instance and read it later:

```js
const origOpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
  this.url = arguments[1];
  return origOpen.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};

const origSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
  if (this.url) {
    console.log("url found:", this.url);
      this.setRequestHeader("A-Header", "Value");
  }
  // prevent error in snippet, uncomment next line
  // return origSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
};

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "https://stackoverflow.com");
xhr.send();
```